# The return type is incompatible with FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(int)

Tags: android

I've Looked at all the solutions here related to my problem,but i can't still solve it.Please i really do need help.I will appreciate any help

What i'm trying to do is porpulate my fragment with a lisview.But the tabsPagerAdapter class keeps on giving me the above error.

```
package com.example.tabswithswipe.adapter;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import com.example.tabswithswipe.GamesFragment;
import com.example.tabswithswipe.MoviesFragment;
import com.example.tabswithswipe.TopRatedFragment;
public class TabsPagerAdapter  extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
        super(fm);
    }
    public Fragment getItem(int index) 
    {
        switch(index)
        {
        case 0:
            //Top Rated fragment activity
            return new TopRatedFragment();

        case 1:
            //Games fragment activity
            return new GamesFragment();

        case 2:
            //Movies fragment activity
            return new MoviesFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        //get item count,equal to number of tabs
        return 3;
    }


}
```

please i will really appreciate any help guys.Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are importing `ListFragment` from the framework, but using `Fragments` from the support library.

Try import the correct `ListFragment`:

```
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
```

And make sure your custom `Fragments` extend `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

Comment: Wow..thanks Alot Sir.It worked like a charm..Thank You

Comment: Pleasure, I've spent unnecessary time on that before.

Comment: I'm writing an android application as my final year project.Is it possible i get your email address so that i can contact you directly,incase i get stuck.That is,if you dont mind.Thanks

Comment: Sorry, no time for one on one support. Good luck though.